# Reporting Services permissions on SQL Server R2 SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm getting the error below when I try and access SSRS on SQL Server 2008 R2

I'm not sure how many others have started using SQL 2008 R2 SSRS, but I am having an issue with getting the error below when I try and access the reports server url

> User does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC)
>   restrictions have been addressed

I can access the url if I run IE as an administrator

Comment: Here is another solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190799/user-mycomputer-myloginname-does-not-have-required-permissions

Comment: I had an intermittent version of this; caused by load balancing over 2 SSRS servers; one with the issue.  The issue in my case was IIS was installed on the faulty server, with the W3SVP service running / using port 80 (the same port SSRS had been configured to use).  Disabling the W3SVP service then restarting SSRS resolved the issue.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This did the trick for me. http://thecodeattic.wordpress.com/category/ssrs/.   Go down to step 35 to see the error you are getting.  Paraphrasing:

Once you're able to log in to YourServer/Reports as an administrator, click Home in the top-right corner, then Folder Settings and New Role Assignment.  Enter your user name and check a box for each role you want to grant yourself.  Finally, click OK.  You should now be able to browse folders without launching your browser with elevated privileges.

Don't forget to set the security at the site level **AND ** at the folder level.

Comment: @AJM, it would have been good if you shared how you had fixed it... because it did not work with me...

Comment: In addition make sure intranet settings are enabled in IE. Even when typing my password in the authentication popup it didn't work for me without intranet settings enabled.

Comment: After running IE in elevated mode ("as administrator") I had to enter the username and password for my local admin account; even my domain account that was in the local admins group wasn't accepted.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was [disabling UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7). This may be because I'm on Windows 7 Home edition.

Comment: NB: Elevation in other browsers (I tested on Chrome and Waterfox) doesn't work. It only worked on IE. I really hope I'm missing something

Comment: @Rick Arthur, what if I'm using Win10 Home Edition and there is no chance to run Explorer as Administrtor?

Comment: @Sher Normally, you would right-click on the Explorer icon, and you would have the 'Run as Administrator' option.  If that doesn't work, try holding down the shift key while you right-click.

Comment: It also works if a role is enabled, something like [domain]\SQL Report Admins

Answer (score 29):

You need to set permissions within SSRS **in two places** to give yourself initial access. The set-up program only gives access to Builtin\Administrators, to gain access in order to do this you need to right click you browser link and choose Run as administrator.

1. Run internet explorer as Administrator
2. Open the report Manager URL, this time you should get in
3. Go to **Site Settings** in the top right
4. Click Security then New Role Assignment
5. Enter your domain\username and select System Administrator, click ok
6. Add other users as necessary
7. Click home, **Folder Settings**, then New Role Assignment
8. Enter your domain\username and select Content Manager, click ok
9. Add other users as necessary
10. Re-open internet explorer (non-admin) and recheck the url.

Comment: Thank you!  Step by step instructions and no outside links, great answer that should be at the top

Comment: @webturner what if I'm using Win10 Home Edition and there is no chance to run Explorer as Administrtor?

Comment: @Sher ,don't use Microsoft EDGE browser , go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer , search for iexplorer and right click Run as Administrator to launch it.

Answer (score 4):

in my case this error resolved by adding permission level to root folder .

i previously only granted permission in 2 place. one in site setting and one in a **new folder** that has custom permission .

### but the user permission to browse the root folder was also required. Note The **"Folder setting"** in root folder

another time i had similar problem and  adding users in the following windows group 
SQLServerReportServerUser$servername$MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER
and running IE as Administrator or turning off UAC resolved my problem .

Comment: Discovered this the hard way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think I tried everything mentioned here, and it still didn't work.  Turns out it didn't recognize my domain login to the server as being in the Administrators group because it was implicit through my membership in another group ( Developers ) which is a member of the Administrators group.

I added my individual domain\login to the Administrators group explicitly, logged off and then logged back on to the box, and IE admitted me to the Report Manager homepage without requiring me to run IE as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

If this still isn't working try unchecking "Enable Protected Mode" in IE.
Add your site to Local Intranet in 
Tools -> Internet Option -> Security Tab
Then uncheck "Enable Protected Mode"
Restart IE

Comment: This sorted it for me when all above failed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after running IE as an administrator, i had to add the url of the report manager to the Local Internet Zones in Internet Explorer, not Trusted Sites.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because of UAC and only when you are running IE on the same computer SSRS is on.

To fix it, you have to add an AD group of the users with read priviledges to the actual SSRS website directories and push the security down. UAC is dumb in how if you are an admin on the box. It won't let you access the data unless you also have access to the data through other means such as a non-administrator AD group that is applied to the files.

Answer (score 0):

**First,** Make sure that the current user is a **member of Local Administrator Group** on the server that running SSRS to can **manage** SSRS permissions,

> **Note:** By default, the local admins have full permission to manage SSRS.

**Now, try to do the following:**

- Run Internet Explorer as Administrator.
- Browse the Report Manager URL.
- Provide the user that has a permission issue the required permission as mentioned at [User does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/02/04/ssrs-permission-issue-user-does-not-have-required-permissions-verify-that-sufficient-permissions-have-been-granted-and-windows-user-account-control-uac-restrictions-have-been-addressed/)

> **Note:** if the issue still exists, so it's not a permission issue, you
>   need to adjust the Internet Explorer settings as mentioned at [User
>   does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions
>   have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions
>   have been addressed](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/02/04/ssrs-permission-issue-user-does-not-have-required-permissions-verify-that-sufficient-permissions-have-been-granted-and-windows-user-account-control-uac-restrictions-have-been-addressed/)