# User '' does not have required permissions, SSRS 2008 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, ssrs-2008

When you try to log into SSRS's root site at http:// (servername)/Reports it displays:

User '' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

This is on a 64 bit edition of Windows 8 Pro, running SQL Server 2008 enterprise.  Everything should be using the local system as the account of execution.

I have tried changing the execution account as my user which is admin, I have added the site as the trusted site, I have UAC turned completely off, I have tried to hit the site with **IE AS ADMIN**, Chrome, and Firefox.  Everything I try the site states back that I don't have the rights.  I go into SQL Server and ensure my roles are everything for my user.  It does not care.  I am currently reinstalling the SSRS node of the SQL Server install but am curious if anyone else had this issue yet.

I am going to try to change my account to a 'local' account as I am thinking that may be an issue yet I don't understand why SQL Server can recognize my login integrated just fine.  Honestly I never ran into this and am wondering if this is an issue just with Windows 8 accessing SQL Server 2008.  I would upgrade but I have a full version of SQL Server 2008 and not of 2012 so I am hesitant to just upgrade unless Express 2012 will come with Business Intelligence Development Studio and SSRS site with tools.

EDIT: 3-8-2016:

1. No answer with: "Just turn on site settings" is valid as this is the first time installing as the admin of the server or machine locally and not able to access the landing page as that admin.
2. No answer with: "Just run IE as admin" will work last I tested that.
3. Answers with "Trusted SITE settings MAY WORK" on Windows 8 and higher as I had a similar problem to this with Windows 10 and on Windows 10 it did fix it.  I am not going to rollback two OS versions to check at home though, sorry.

I don't get how this question can be existing for a while and people are now on a mission to claim it is duplicate when the very answer is different than the potential duplicate.  That whole thread deals with someone able to get into the site with elevated permission and just not setting up roles and users after the fact.   This is the main user of the machine not getting to the landing page as an admin to the site listed as the default landing.  Not even the same ballpark.  Getting into a page as an admin to let local users in versus the highest level God user not getting in is not the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reporting Services permissions on SQL Server R2 SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389040/reporting-services-permissions-on-sql-server-r2-ssrs)

Comment: Not a duplicate, IE as admin does not fix this as that answer says.  Honestly I also do not get how I keep flagging people that right 'run as admin' as bad and it keeps getting thought that it will fix everything in every case.  Answer lies in SSRS does not recognize local admin and you cannot even get to landing page even with elevated rights of IE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay this is really annoying what needed to be done but here goes.

From what I kept reading Windows 8 does not by default enable the default administrator account.

I usually don't use this account but in this case I was desperate as my account could not get in.

I understand ONCE YOU ARE IN you can set the site settings, that does not help if you cannot even see the site's main landing page to see that setting.

The steps I took to finally resolve were;

1. Uninstall SSRS Node COMPLETELY by going to control panel>SQL Server 2008>Remove>Check Reporting Services
2. Enable default admin account: command prompt>run as administrator>net user administrator p@ssw0rD, hit enter.
3. New line: net user administrator /active:yes
4. Reboot
5. Reinstall SSRS from disc with logging in as default administrator
6. Install SP3 as administrator
7. Go to IE.exe DIRECTLY in Windows 8: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe>Run as administrator.
8. Go to http:// (servername)/Reports
9. You SHOULD now be able to finally see site settings.  NOW YOU CAN FOLLOW everyone's directions of adding YOUR USER under site settings.  Also go to folder permissions and add the user as a default here as well.
10. (optional) For safety I would hide the default admin account now by using step 2 but substitute /active:no in.

If your main admin can't open the door, no one is getting in.  That was the main issue I was having.  My default admin could not get in.  Now everything is working fine and dandy like it should with deploying from BIDS as well.

Answer (score 14):

Everything in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442782/849741) is true but don't reinstall all of SSRS thats nonsense...

Windows 8

1. Disable UAC
2. Enable Administrator Account (You can go to Control Panel >  Computer Management > Users)
3. Restart PC
4. Run IE ad Administrator when prompted login with your local Administrator account you enabled.
5. You will need to adjust site settings security and folder settings security.  Easy fast fix just add "Everyone" in both of those with full rights.

Problem solved!

Comment: For me, running IE was the key. Running Chrome as admin still caused the same error message.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue myself but with Windows 7 and SQL Server 2008. I resolved the issue following the instructions from Suresh Kumar's blog post at http://skamie.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/ssrs-and-uac/

In a nutshell here are the steps you need to take to resolve this issue:

Start your browser using 'run as Administrator'.

Navigate to the report manager and under Site Settings -> Security assign your account or the local administrators group to the System Administration role.

Then navigate to the home folder and under the security settings assign your account or the local administrators group to the Browser, Conent Manager, My Reports, Publisher and Report Builder roles.

Now you should be able to run your browser as normal and access SSRS without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Windows 8 system (32 bit) with SQL Server 2008R2. When I started IE using 'run as Administrator' it still asked for a user name and password and resulted in "user does not have permissions"-error when I entered my user name and password. This is what fixed it for me:

I disabled UAC in the registry (Set HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA to 0). I first set notify-level under Control Panel | System and Security | Change User Account Control to the lowest level but that didn't make any difference.

After reboot I started IE using 'run as Administrator'. Went to Report Manager | Site Settings | Security: added my account as System administrator.

Still in Report Manager I went to Home | Folder Settings and added my account with role Content Manager.

I enabled UAC through Control Panel | System and Security | Change User Account Control settings by setting it to default level again. (Reboot required)

When I run IE as Administrator now and supply my user name and password it does show the homepage of the report manager.

Comment: I will give this a shot but everyone keeps assuming you can see 'site settings'.  I get a denial before I even can see anything.  I just reinstalled last night and now I can get to the main landing page but without the site settings.  It just states: "Home, My Subscriptions, Help" now.  More background on me, I have set up SSRS about 10 times in the past so I know the little gotchas with the Groups and folder settings with deployments.  I can't even get my main user account that is the admin that did the install to get to the site.

Answer (score 0):

**Run** Internet Explorer **as administrator** (right click on the Taskbar icon)

Step 1 :: Add your local username to the **Site Settings** security roles page. (Security - System Administrator)

Step 2 :: Add your local username to the **Folder Settings** on the home page. (Select Content Manager)

Close the Administrator IE session.
Open IE in normal mode under your user account.

Comment: "I understand ONCE YOU ARE IN you can set the site settings, that does not help if you cannot even see the site's main landing page to see that setting."

Comment: You can, just run IE as Administrator. If you can't even see the page then your OS is screwed...

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1

I resolved this with help from the answer by Austin McLaughlin posted earlier. In my case I had been logged in with a local account that had administrator privileges, but attempting to http://127.0.0.1/Reports (hearinafter referred to as "the Reporting Services Manager") produced the error reported by the OP.

The key for me was that the Administrator account was disabled by default in my Windows 8.1 laptop. Note that I did not originally have Windows 8.1 Pro, so there was no "Local Users and Groups" under "Computer Management". Thus, I had to purchase the [Windows 8.1 Pro Pack](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Windows-8.1-Pro-Pack/productID.288392300) online from MS for $100.

1. In Windows Explorer, right click on the Computer node and select "Manage".
2. Navigate to Local Users and Groups > Users
3. Right click on Administrator and select Properties
4. De-select "Account is disabled"
5. Restart PC
6. Log in to the PC as Administrator (I did not have to enter a password for the Administrator account on first login.)
7. From the desktop, run IE. No need to run as Administrator, of course, since you logged in as Administrator.
8. Navigate to the Reporting Services Manager.

At this point you should be logged in to the Report Administrator and on the Home screen. I had not been able to get this far before.

9. On the Home screen, click "New Role Assignment"
10. In "Group or user name", enter the local administrator account you use for development; i.e.: [yourmachine]\[username]
11. Select all the checkboxes (shortcut is to click the checkbox to the left of "Role") and click OK.
12. In the upper right hand side of the page, click Site Settings.
13. On the left side of the page, click Security.
14. Click "New Role Assignment"
15. In "Group or user name" enter the same account as in step 10
16. Check "System Administrator" checkbox and click OK
17. As a precaution, disable the Administrator account that you enabled in step 4.
18. Log out, then back in with your local account from step 10.
19. In IE, browse to the Reporting Services Manager. Note: It was not necessary for me to start IE as Administrator.

At this point you should be able to access Reporting Services Manager page, and configure reporting services further.

Comment: I think at this point this is kicking a dead horse to provide any more answers to this.  The question was marked as answered over two years ago.  Especially given steps 9 through 19 are above what the question wanted and the OS is Windows 8 not 8.1.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This was my first post, the marked answer did not completely solve my issue, and since I found this thread with one of my many Google searches I thought it would help someone else in my situation. I will work to improve.

Answer (score -1):

Change service account type as "**Network Service**" in service account tab then stop and start service and run IE as Administrator.

Answer (score -1):

From **Reporting Services Configuration Manager** you can get to the node **Report Manager Url**. The URL works from this screen. Now you can use the *Folder Settings* to add yourself as a *Content Manager*, etc... Now the url will work for your user.

Answer (score -1):

In IE, just add Add the reporting services website to "Local  intranet" sites. 
That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Just open IE as Run As Administrator and just type URL as http://localhost/reports