# User mycomputer\myloginName does not have required permissions

Tags: windows-7, ssrs-2008

I am trying to access the report manager url for SSRS. But, I keep on getting the error below -

User mycomputer\myloginName does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

I tried to run my browser as admin as described here - [User '' does not have required permissions, SSRS 2008 on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433068/user-does-not-have-required-permissions-ssrs-2008-on-windows-8)
with no success. I also don't see the 'site settings' on top-right corner as mentioned by so many people. Also, I cannot go through the pain of reinstalling SQL server all over again. I don't want to disable UAC.

I am unable to do anything because of this problem.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: this post also does not help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389040/reporting-services-permissions-on-sql-server-r2-ssrs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is for Internet Explorer. I don't know how it can be done for firefox or chrome.

Link 1 - 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/9b5a8763-84ce-46d0-b011-067ad39223d1/

See the solutions by Chirag Shah. Follow only up to step 13. I could not follow Step 14 because I found no home dialog box.

In the steps Chirag talks about some URL's. I don't really understand the meaning of any of those URL's. So, I used the URL under "Report Manager URL" in "Reporting Services Configuration Manager". It was

```
http://localhost:8080/MyReportServer.
```

The 8080 is a port number.

Once you finished this, go to the link below and follow all the steps - 
http://www.soheib.com/technical-knowledge/sql-server-2012-reporting-services-uac-user-access-control/

In the 7th step, I saw a lot of check boxes. I selected all of them. 
Finally, I can rest in peace. Hope it works for you too.

Also, when making the accounts described in the above link, you might see "BUILTIN\Administrators" account. Ignore it -  thats what i did.

```
                             **END  OF POST**
```

---

Steps taken from Chirag Shah's post -

1. Configure the report server for local administration. To access the report server and Report Manager locally, follow these steps:
2. Start Windows Internet Explorer.
3. On the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
4. Click Security.
5. Click Trusted Sites.
6. Click Sites.
7. Under Add this Web site to the zone, type http://ServerName. If you are not using HTTPS for the default site, click to clear the Require server certification (https:) for all sites in this zone check box.
8. Click Add.
9. Repeat step 7f and step 7g to add the http   localhost URL, and then click Close.
10. Note This step enables you to start Internet Explorer and open either the localhost or the network computer name of the server for both the Report Server application and the Report Manager application.
11. Create role assignments that explicitly grant you access together with full permissions. To do this, follow these steps:
12. Start Internet Explorer together with the Run as administrator option. To do this, click Start, click All Programs, right-click Internet Explorer, and then click Run as administrator.
13. Open Report Manager. By default, the Report Manager URL is http://ServerName/reports. If you use SQL Server Express with Advanced Services SP2, the Report Manager URL is http://ServerName/reports$sqlexpress. If you use a named instance of Reporting Services, the Report Manager URL is http://ServerName/reports$InstanceName

Comment: Related post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389040/reporting-services-permissions-on-sql-server-r2-ssrs

Comment: I tried to do the same thing in Firefox, that is, add the SSRS localhost URL to "trusted sites". But, it does not work. Here is the link I used for trying that - 
http://hdc.tamu.edu/Academics/eLearning/Make_the_eLearning_Site_a_Trusted_Site_on_Your_Browser.php

Comment: If you are using DOMAINNAME/user that will not work if you are not on a domain. You can make a user name as admin on the server you need, then delegate responsibility from there.

Comment: @ltn - i am not familiar with the technical terms you mentioned. can you explain that in plain English ? :)

Answer (score 0):

i was receiving blank page after i was logging exactly 3 times on my report server URL. 
i've Turn Off Internet Explorer Enhanced Security. On different OS's it is in different location. find the location and turn it off. 
I hope this will help you.