# SSRS SQL Reporting Services permissions in EDGE Browser

Tags: reporting-services, windows-10, ssrs-2012, microsoft-edge

I'm getting the following error when I try to access SSRS Reports through the Edge browser in Windows 10.

```
User does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed
```

This is similar to [other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389040/reporting-services-permissions-on-sql-server-r2-ssrs) and the only workaround seems to be to use another browser such as IE which still exists in Windows10.

I have tried accessing via IE, changing permissions for the user and retrying Edge but that doesn't work, there are several issues raised over at [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8cb58293-94b1-424a-a474-bbc1f8ae55af/microsoft-edge-browser-to-use-ssrs-in-native-mode?forum=sqlreportingservices) with no solution as to how to make this work in Edge.

The end users of the reports will be upgrading to Windows10 soon and expect to be using Edge as the recommended browser both by Microsoft and by the company process guidelines - I need a better workaround than falling back to IE.

Answer (score 0):

As per my R & D on reporting servers, i have find out one thing that should be common like -

if we give permission to report server we may fist try to open internet explorer or edge browser on `**run as administrator**` mode follow this link for reference -

https://thecodeattic.wordpress.com/category/ssrs/