# rsAccessDenied - SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have installed SQL Server 2012 on my Windows 10 computer. When I try to access Reporting Services via the Browser such as Chrome or Firefox, It prompts me for username/password (In which I do enter) but then it gives me an error

> (Reporting Services Error: The permissions granted to user
>   'ComputerName\User' are insufficient for performing this operation.
>   (rsAccessDenied)).

I have tried many solutions such as Internet Options and SQL server management studio. I have spent most of my time trying to figure this out but have given up hope.

Comment: What URL are you using to attempt to access reporting services?  Are you attempting to access reporting services from a different machine?  Have you grant permissions reporting services for the account you are trying to access with?

Comment: @BobF I am using http://<computer-name>/<reports>, I am using it locally and I set up SQL server 2012. When it asks me for Username and Password my input is valid but it still gives me the rsAccessDenied error

Comment: Have you read over this posting - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389040/reporting-services-permissions-on-sql-server-r2-ssrs ?
This article is a excellent guide to setting up SSRS for the first time - https://thecodeattic.wordpress.com/category/ssrs/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to access Report Manager application (and not the Report *Server*) try this:

- Run Internet Explorer **as Administrator**
- Browse to Report Manager    URL e.g. http://localhost/reports
- You should see the Report Manager "home" page
- Go to the Security settings for the home page and explicitly add your user account with the "Content Manager" role

You should now be able to browse to the home page with IE or Firefox. Note that **Chrome** is [not a supported browser for SSRS 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the fix but I figured out why It was not allowing me access. I am using windows 10 and turns out doing this process on chrome, edge, or Firefox does not work.

Comment: Prokaryote is right. I opened InternetExplorer (Run as admin), follow the above instructions, and I'm in! MS Edge doesn't work for this.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled doing this with IE now officially unsupported (with chromium edge installed). Everytime I opened IE it would close immediately. To get around this, create a Windows Shortcut (lnk) file with this command:

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -extoff http://localhost/Reports

NOTE: The shortcut must be opened as Administrator.