# SSRS on a Domain Controller / DNS Server

Tags: reporting-services

I have installed SSRS on a server which is also both a domain controller and a DNS server and am having some difficulty setting up permissions.

The symptom is the "User does not have required permissions" message, the solution for which is well documented online (e.g. [Reporting Services permissions on SQL Server R2 SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389040/reporting-services-permissions-on-sql-server-r2-ssrs)).

However this solution is not working for me. I have opened IE as administrator and added my domain user with full privileges under both site settings and folder settings, yet still I can only open Report Manager when I open IE as admin, and furthermore when I do so I can only open it with via localhost and not via the machine name.

I suspect the issue may be related to the fact that the server is also a domain controller and a DNS server but really don't know.

EDIT: I should expand on what is happening when I enter the machine name: I am being prompted for credentials 3 times and then getting a blank screen.

Comment: I think you are entering into a whole world of heartache following this path. Where is the SQL Server - why is SSRS not installed there?

Comment: SSRS is not installed on the SQL server as we are using an AlwaysOn Availability Group, and as SSRS can't be part of the failover mechanism, the decision was taken to place SSRS on a separate server which it turns out is also a domain controller.

Comment: Fair enough - but I wouldn't have it anywhere near DNS or the DC.

Comment: Oh dear, could you please tell me why you say that?

Comment: Do a quick search on google... there are all sorts of security implications. On top of that, I wouldn't want _any_ applications installed on those two servers from a best practice point of view :-)

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as your service account for SSRS?

Built-in Windows service accounts (Local Service or Network Service) are not supported as report server service accounts on a computer that is a domain controller.

More information [here on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160340.aspx)

Comment: The service account is a domain user which is part of the built-in administrators group