# Report sever not working showing error message "Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted " How to Solve it?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Report sever not working showing error message "Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed" How to Solve it?
This is my error Window
[image: Click here This is my error Window]

Comment: refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389040/reporting-services-permissions-on-sql-server-r2-ssrs

Comment: That solution for Report server url run in IE as an administrator that's working but my problem i'm run in IE as an administrator that also showing same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add at least one user as a **System Administrator**. You can do this in few steps.

1. Run *Internet Explorer* as Administrator;
2. Enter the URL for Report Server Manager (http://localhost/Reports);
3. Click **Site Settings** in the upper right corner. That will get you to the settings section;
4. On the left side click **Security**;
5. Click **New Role Assignment** this will take you to the page where new users can be added with different level of security (admin or user).
   [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157363.aspx) is a summary of the roles available;
6. Add your username and choose *System Administrator* role below.

Comment: This solution for Report server url run in IE as an administrator that's working but my problem i'm run in IE as an administrator that also showing same error

Comment: Tghis report server is on your computer or somewhere else?

Comment: in my computer that's not working how to solve the server prb?

Comment: If it is on your computer you can enter Start->SQL Server 20XX->Reporting Service configuration. On *Service Account* tab yoyu can change by which user will service run - change to your account. Then go to the http://localhost/Reports_INSTANCENAME/Pages/Settings.aspx and add your account as Administrator the way provided in answer. Then change *Service Account* setting to build-in (back it was)

Comment: I'm changed the Use built-in account: Local system then applying time ask the model popup "Backup Encryption Key" that's ask file location and password

Comment: Better use *services.msc* and change account (run as) there. Or if you know login and password of user that runs Report Service? you need to authorize under  that credentials to you Report Service in browser.